Keep Spring application on while performing tests
I'm in the process of writing tests (JUnit5) for a Spring + Hibernate (MySQL) application.
Every time i start a test (or suite of tests) the application starts, runs the tests then exits. The startup time is about 50 seconds so running tests multiple times - especially when writing and debugging the tests themselves - can be quite tiring; having to wait ~50secs every mvn test (or IntelliJ's test button) is not optimal.
So I'd like a way to sort of start the application once at the start of my dev session keep in running for the duration of all tests, that I can run as many times as I need, and manually shut it down when I want to.
Edit: I'm @Autowireing Spring services for integration tests so my tests are annotated with @SpringBootTest, I need the app to start.

Do you really need Spring for the tests? If it is a simple unit to test don't use Spring for testing, just create the objects yourselves.

I'm performing integration tests as well and so I'm autowiring spring services. Nearly all tests have @SpringBootTest.

If nearly all your tests have @SpringBootTest you are on a wrong testing approach as I doubt you need the full application for everything, you should only have that for integration tests. Ofcourse you could keep the server running but that would pose other problems, what do you do when you change code? Hotreload is not really an option as it runs outside of the control of your test/ide now. It would also not work with @SpringBootTest as you cannot access the context running that application. Also a lot of things (like @MockBean, @TestPropertySource and others) influence what's loaded.
